# How to print ASCII codes for letters?

Tags: c

How do I create a program where the input of a letter (a-z) is converted to ASCII and printed out. I am stuck at the point where it has to show all the ASCII numbers before it.

Let's say if the user inputs the character `c`, I want to print out 97,98,99 for character inputs a,b,c respectively.

I am somewhat a beginner. Pretty sure I have to use a loop.

---

Hi, as I am a beginner can you possibly check my way of doing it, unsure where I am doing wrong. Your code has a few things which I am unfamiliar with. I am aiming to restrict it to only A-Z. So here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c,z;
    printf("Enter An English upper case letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &z);
    for (c=65;c<91;c++)
    {
        if(c==z)
            printf("%c",z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO !! Can you include the code of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have added. What I tried is since I want the letters from A-Z I checked the ASCII code and limited the  for between that. But I am unsure on what to print as or what to do next as I am confused.

Comment: Edited my original answer considering your specific case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_ASCII_value(char c)
{
    printf("The ASCII value of %c = %d", c, c);
}

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    get_ASCII_value(c);

    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, `%d` prints the ASCII value for that specific char

As for your specific case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c,z;

    printf("Enter An English upper case letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &z);

    if (z < 65 || z > 90)
        return 0;

    for (c = 65; c <= z; c++)
        printf("The ASCII value of %c = %d\n", c, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciated.

Comment: Technically `"%d"` prints the decimal value for the integer provided as the argument -- which will be the ASCII value for an ASCII character.

Comment: @newbie_freak you should accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void)
{
    for(uint8_t c = 0; c < UCHAR_MAX; ++c)
    {
        uint8_t out[2] = {c};
        printf("%d (%s)\n", c, isprint(c)? out : "*unprintable*");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

###Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4288KB
0 (*unprintable*)
1 (*unprintable*)
2 (*unprintable*)
3 (*unprintable*)
4 (*unprintable*)
5 (*unprintable*)
[....]
29 (*unprintable*)
30 (*unprintable*)
31 (*unprintable*)
32 ( )
33 (!)
34 (")
35 (#)
36 ($)
37 (%)
38 (&)
39 (')
40 (()
41 ())
42 (*)
43 (+)
[...]
65 (A)
66 (B)
67 (C)
68 (D)
69 (E)
70 (F)
71 (G)
```

Comment: Fun variation on [Generate Full ASCII-Chart in Single Loop](https://pastebin.com/e860KjHg) with control character identification.